# Finding all paths through a 4x4 grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, graph, big-o

how do you go about solving this problem ::

**A robot is located at the top-left corner of a 4x4 grid. The robot can move either up, down, left, or right, but can not visit the same spot twice. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid.**

My ideas:

Backtracking solution where we go through the tree of all solutions and print once we reach goal cell.  I implemented that but I'm not sure if it's correct or makes sense, or if it is even the right approach.  I've posted code here and would much appreciate if someone could explain what's wrong with it.

Recursive solution where I start at start cell, and find the path to the goal cell from each of its neighboring cells recursively, with the base case being hitting the goal cell.

QUESTIONS:

1) Are these two ways of expressing the same idea?

2) Do these ideas even make sense?

3) What is the time complexity of each of these solutions?  I think the second one is 4^n?

4) Does my backtracking code make sense?

5) Is there a much simpler way to do this?

Here is my code, which prints the correct number of paths for N = 4.  Is it correct?

```
#define N 4
int counter = 0;
bool legal_move(int x, int y, int array[N+2][N+2]){
  bool ret = (array[x][y] == 1);
  array[x][y] = 0;
  return ret;
}

/*
void print_array(int array[N+2][N+2]){
  for(int i = 0; i < N+2; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N+2; j++)
      cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << endl;
}
*/

void print_paths(int x, int y, int n, int m, int array[N+2][N+2]){
  if(x == n && y == m){
    print_array(array);
    counter++;
  }
  else {
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      if(legal_move(x + dx, y + dy, array)){
        print_paths(x + dx, y + dy, n, m, array);
        array[x+dx][y+dy] = 1;
      }
      swap(dx,dy);
      if(i == 1)
        dx = -dx;
    }
  }
}

int main(){

  int array[N+2][N+2];

  for(int i = 1; i < N+1; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j < N+1; j++)
      array[i][j] = 1;

  for(int i = 0; i < N+2; i++)
    array[0][i] = array[i][0] = array[N+1][i] = array[i][N+1] = 0;

//print_array(array);
  array[1][1] = 0;  //Set start cell to be seen.
  print_paths(1,1,N,N,array);
  cout << counter << endl;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should choose a better way for your output, so it's clear what the path is. Maybe replace `1` in each output by a direction, like `^` or `v`, or print a sequence number (1, 2, 3, ...). In addition, what's about the 5 printed matrices and 4 found paths? This seems unnecessarily obscure.

Comment: Agreed.  Sorry about that.  It's very confusing.  I tried doing a sequence but scrapped it.  The first matrix is just the matrix before I search for paths.  1 = unseen, 0 = seen.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same idea.

The problem with your code is that you haven't implemented 'but can not visit the same spot twice' correctly.

Suppose that your robot has gone from S to A by some path, and you are now examining whether to go to B adjacent to A. The test should be 'has the robot been to B before on *the current path*'. But what you have implemented is 'has the robot visited B before on *any path*'.

In other words you need to modify `print_paths` to take an extra parameter for the current path, and use that to implement the test correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... But don't I do that by setting array[x+dx][y+dy] = 1 after print_paths?

Comment: No because that's a permanent change to the array, and prevents any future path going though that location.

Comment: The way I did it 1 signifies unseen cell and 0 signifies a seen cell.  I know that's confusing.  So that would make it so that a future path CAN go through that location.. ( I think )

Comment: I seem to actually be getting too *many* paths as opposed to too few.  So I think I'm not pruning the tree correctly.  For example, for N=2, I get 4 paths, when I believe there are only 2

Comment: That's because you haven't implemented the test correctly. For instance nothing in you code prevents the robot from the start moving left, then right. Only now would it be illegal to move left *again*. Like I said you need an extra parameter with the current path.

Comment: So should I just have a vector that represents the current path passed along as an argument then?

Comment: Never mind.  You helped me solve it.  You were right:  The mistake was that I never set the start cell to be seen.  So my code permitted retracing steps over the start cell and giving spurious results.  Thank you!

Comment: I believe you but I'm not able to understand your explanation.  Also the online judge is accepting my solution for the number of paths.  That doesn't mean it's not wrong though.  Can you go into a little as to why the implementation doesn't work?  As I understand it, it goes down the tree of a path until it hits the goal cell, increments the counter, and then on the way back up the tree it wipes all that history away only to start anew.  Where exactly is the flaw?

Comment: OK apologies, I think you are right. What confused me was that you set the array in `legal_move`. I missed that (from the start I think). It's bad style because you are mixing a test (is this a legal move?) with an action (mark this cell as seen). For better style you should have `array[x+dx][y+dy] = 1;` before the recursive call to `print_paths` instead of in `legal_move`.

Comment: Yeah that is actually terrible style to mutate state in a boolean check.  Should have refactored my code before I posted, but I didn't know why it wasn't working (which you found).  Thanks!

Comment: Can I arrive at a more faster solution for a 4Xn board where n can be order of 10^6 or so?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer, which talks mostly about complexity (I think your code is correct, after the minor bugfix suggested by john, and backtracking is probably the simplest way to do what you want).

The time complexity seems something like `O(3^n^2)` to me - there are at most `n^2` nodes, and at each node you want to check 3 possibilities. There are actually less nodes, because of the way backtracking works, but the complexity is *at least* `O(2^(n^2/4))`, so it's greater than any exponential. (the `O` in the last formula is actually a theta).

The below diagram describes this lower bound. Cells marked by `?` have a "decision" in them - the robot may decide to go straight or turn. There are at least `n^2/4` such cells, so the number of paths is at least `2^(n^2/4)`.

```
?->-?->-?->-V
| | | | | | |
>-^ >-^ >-^ V
            |
V-<-?-<-?-<-?
| | | | | | |
V ^-< ^-< ^-<
|
...
```

Comment: Can I arrive at a more faster solution for a 4Xn board where n can be order of 10^6 or so?

Comment: @sudeepdino008 Which problem are you trying to solve? If there are 3^10^6 solutions, you surely don't want to examine them all. Maybe you only want to find one "best" solution? Maybe you want to print the number of possible solutions?

Comment: I'm not looking to print path, just the number of ways. I stumbled across this: https://oeis.org/A181688    which gives a recurrence relation, although I'm not sure how to arrive at that.